# Is firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() async?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a real time chat application in firestore and I'm currently having a problem reading back message timestamps. I'm using an onSnapshot listener to get updates from my messages collection, however I'm finding that I'm getting an undefined error on the latest timestamp which leads to me to think that the serverTimestamp() is an asynchronous method on the server side. I cant find any documentation regarding this

Is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`serverTimestamp()` just returns a static sentinel value on the client.  It can't possibly generate an error.  All this sentinel value does is tell the server to use its sense of current time to populate the field where it appears.

Comment: I don't understand this then, I'm using the toDate() function to convert this server timestamp to a date I can display to my users. However it throws the error on only the latest message, and it's specific to the timestamp property. Any ideas what could be causing this?


Edit: I should clarify, I'm only receiving the error the moment I receive the new message via the onSnapshot listener, the value updates correctly in firestore.

Comment: Is it possible that the new document is being returned before the server populates the timestamp field?

Comment: It's not possible for the document to be available without the Timestamp object populated in it.

Comment: FWIW I was seeing this behaviour as well. i.e. Set a serverTimestamp() field and query immediately using the web SDK in react native and the timestamp field was null in the returned doc. For me the issue was that I wasn't waiting for the save promise to complete before running the query. I tried replicating with the node.js SDK and couldn't replicate it there but it did exist in my react native app.

Comment: I'm facing the exact issue when adding a new message and trying to use toDate() on the timestamp field, is there a solution for this?